# React: Typescript - ignoring Interface on assignment

Tags: reactjs, typescript, constructor, state

I have a `interface` called `State` defined, and when I set the state in the `constructor` it is ignoring the interface.

In the `constructor` I set `person` which is part of the `interface State` to the variable `somePerson` which is not of the `interface Person`, so it should throw a `TypeError` but its not

---

**Interfaces:**

```
interface Person{
    id: number;
    name: string;
    phone: string;
    email: string;
    photo: string;
    position: string;
}
interface Test {
    workday: any;
    person: Person;
}
interface Props {
    data: Test;   
    settings: any;
}
interface State{
    person: Person;
    contract: number;
    manager: Manager;
    workday: Workday;
}
```

**Code:**

```
export class MyComponent extends Component<Props,State> {
    constructor(props: Props){
        super(props);

        // destructuring from the @props
        // this [person] is not of the interface type Person
        let { person: somePerson } = this.props.data;

        this.state = {
            ...this.state,
            person: somePerson // not of type Person
        }
    }
}
```

---

**Question:** why is it allowing me to set `state.person` to a variable that is not of the type `interface Person`?

Comment: Does 'somePerson' have any of the properties in the Person interface in common?

Comment: @rrd no it doesn't completely different object keys.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Typescript can't know if your `any` variable holds an instance of your object or not. It's anything, so it could be an instance of your object.

Consider this

```
const x: any = {};

// valid
let y: string = x;

// invalid
y = 1;

let num: any = 1;

// valid
y = num;
```

Basically you shouldn't be using `any` in typescript (at least my rule of thumb), because whats the use of typescript in that case? But if you want to use `any`, then you'll just have to deal with such "weird" scenarios.

Comment: gotcha, I would have to define the interfaces for the nested `objects` in the `interface Props` then it wouldn't be `any`

Comment: Exactly! It's always easier to use any in some cases just to hack it and make it work, but when you encounter bug later on, its pretty hard to fix it, so try force types as much as possible and use any if you really have to.

Comment: wait I just updated and still not working, I'll update the code base so you can see

Comment: its not of type `any` anymore and is of type `Person` which is good, but it should of fail on the passdown from the parent > child component in the `this.props`

Comment: @JordanDavis I'm not sure what is the questions now? It fails or?

Answer (score 0):

Try explicitly settings the state

```
export class MyComponent extends Component<Props,State> {
    state: State;
    constructor(props: Props){
        super(props);

        // destructuring from the @props
        // this [person] is not of the interface type Person
        let { person: somePerson } = this.props.data;

        this.state = {
            ...this.state,
            person: somePerson // not of type Person
        }
    }
}
```